# JSON iteration several layers deep

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I a project with a fairly deep JSON structure. I am trying to access a link to an image in my JSON file, but my current solution throws an error. Below is my code including the result that shows up in the code from `console.dir(item.Images)` Any help would be much appreciated!

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON("item-data.json", function(results) {
        $.each(results.CatalogEntryView, function(index, item) {
            console.dir(item.Images);

            document.getElementById("productImage").innerHTML = item.Images.PrimaryImage.image
        });
    });
```

**JSON Tree Structure in Console and Error Being Thrown**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images and PrimaryImage are arrays, so I think you want to access them as arrays, as so:

```
 document.getElementById("productImage").innerHTML = item.Images[0].PrimaryImage[0].image
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimaryImage is an Array. Use `document.getElementById("productImage").innerHTML = item.Images[0].PrimaryImage[0].image`